# TextToSpeech fall back to back end service when pre-recorded wav file missing

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an application which uses the TextToSpeech to announce reference numbers. As the announcements will consist only of 10 digits and the 26 letters of the alphabet, I thought I'd take advantage of prerecorded wav files which I made using the synthesizetofile method in another app.

The documentation states that if the specified file is missing, then the TTS engine will use the network to synthesize on line. I've set up the TTS like so:

```
String filePrefix = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + this.getString(R.string.package_name) + "/files/";

        int rv = 0;
        for (char c = 'A'; c<= 'Z'; c++){
            mWavFileName = filePrefix + Character.toString(c) + ".wav";
             rv  = mTts.addSpeech(Character.toString(c), mWavFileName);
        }
```

Where I've defined

```
TextToSpeech mTts;
String mWavFileName;
```

If the files are present then my code which speaks the letter

```
mTts.speak("A", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

works fine. If the file is missing then the behaviour as described in [An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)  isn't implemented.

*This way any call to speak() for the same string content as wakeUpText will result in the playback of destFileName. If the file is missing, then speak will behave as if the audio file wasn't there, and will synthesize and play the given string.*

I don't see this at all. If the file is missing nothing gets spoken. The return value 'rv' never shows an error if the file is missing. Is there any way to correct this behaviour, other than checking that the file exists before executing the 'addSpeech' line?